# How to use 'my own self' in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, phrases

Would you say "My own self is doing **his** homework" or "My own self is doing **my** homework"? Or is it wrong to use "my own self" in this way?

Technically, I think it should be possible even if not widely used (searching on google gives no results; never read anything that resembles with this structure) and I'm more inclined towards the former. But both of them sound unnatural.

Context: I was writing a blog post when I happened to just write the following sentence down:

> Deadline is knocking on the door like my own decrepit self banging his
> head on the wall.

On rereading, I realized that it sounds off. I'm sure I can phrase it differently if it comes to that, but I'd like to know anyway.

Comment: I would use **its** not _his_ or _my_, but I want to know their opinions too.

Comment: 'His' (or 'her', as it may be) but this is a 'poetic' or idiomatic usage of language, as I'm sure you know already. It has the implication of the 'self' as separate from you (huh?! :-) ) carrying out his/her own thing, rather than doing "your" homework.

Comment: @TasneemZh "It's" sounds even more unnatural, even if that might end up being grammatically correct.

Comment: @seventyeightist But it isn't blatantly wrong, is it? I don't mind the sentence being 'poetic', as you say, as long as it isn't wrong and doesn't have a definite correction.

Comment: The entire sentence sounds bad:  "I did his homework myself." My own decrepit self is another thing. That could be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "My own self is doing his homework"; "My own self is doing my homework"

I agree with the @seventyeightist's comment - this is a "poetic" usage of English. And I would say "self" is in the third person, so "his" or "her" makes more sense than "my". But - I think your blog post has a more likely usage - "my own decrepit self" sounds better than "my own self", because the use of a modifier in the middle makes the use of "my own self" sound less gratuitous. So I would say either "My own *decrepit* [or whatever description] self is doing his homework," or simply "I am doing my homework." And definitely don't use the reflexive object pronoun "myself" as the subject - as in, "Myself is doing my homework"- that would be very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Example: "I ended up having to take care of it my own self."

The -own- in "my own self" ("myownself"/my-own-self) is a sort of infix (as opposed to a prefix or a suffix) that intensifies the reflexivity of the pronoun "myself."

Another example of infixation: unbe-fuckin-lievable.

It's my strong impression that this is predominantly an African American Vernacular English form -- or generally Southern?

Comment: No, I don't think "unbe-fuckin-lievable" is particular to AAVE or Southern dialects.

Comment: Nope, expletive infixation is universal, remarkably so in fact. It's a fun subject to read about.